# angular2 websocket error: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular-cli.
I am trying to implement this example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-websocket-service

I have created my service, and I want to use it directly in AppComponent.

This is what I have:

**app/app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WebSocketService } from 'angular2-websocket-service'
import { MyWebsocketService } from './websocket/mywebsocket.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    WebSocketService,
    MyWebsocketService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app/app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MyWebsocketService} from './websocket/mywebsocket.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'title';

  constructor(private mywebsocket: MyWebsocketService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mywebsocket.connect();
  }
}
```

**app/websocket/mywebsocket.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebSocketService } from 'angular2-websocket-service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share'

@Injectable()
export class MyWebsocketService {
  private q: Observable<any>
  private w: Observable<any>

  constructor(private socketFactory: WebSocketService) { }

  public connect() {
    this.q = new Observable<any>()
    this.w = this.socketFactory.connect('ws://localhost:8080/myapp/cswebsocket', this.q).share()
    this.w.subscribe()
  }
}
```

And here is what I get:

> ```
> > core.js:1350 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of
> > undefined
> ```

Why would this.w be undefined? How can I solve this?

Comment: I see that you declared input stream (q) as observable. Shouldn't it be a queuing subject?

Comment: I am confused a bit about it. In the example it says that it is optional, and subscribe method requires as second parameter an observable. Finally I will try to do in that way and see what happens. However, queueing the messages is not something that is always wanted. I think there should be another trick.